# Count word occurrence for all the files in a folder using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a lot of text files like this

```
D1|This is text
H1|This is line
```

I would like to count and sum all the occurrence of "D1" in all these files in a folder.

I tried

```
 Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.text" -Recurse | Select-String -pattern "D1" -AllMatches).matches.count
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Define `not working`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I missed the left parenthesis for the command

```
 (Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.manifest" -Recurse | Select-String -pattern "D1" -AllMatches).matches.count
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: Is there a way to split the results per date?